# Android set cycle process bar color

Tags: android, process, colors, statusbar, cycle

How could I change color of cycle process bar? In Android 5, the default color is green but I would like to change it.

i am setting the background but it's not the right way since the whole space surrounding the progressbar will be colored.

```
progressBar.setBackgroundResource(drawable);
```

I also tried

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
```

But it didn't response anything.

Do you guys have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tint it with setColorFilter:

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

[image]